# Update minibuffer in the isearch-update-post-hook

Tags: emacs, elisp, minibuffer, isearch

In my search to find a simpler solution that the one found ["1 of n" result for Emacs search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764130/1-of-n-result-for-emacs-search) I've come up with the following package

https://github.com/nordlow/elisp/blob/master/mine/indexed-isearch.el

But the information displayed is delayed one key-stroke. How do fix this? My guess is that I either should call some function that updates the minibuffer at the end of `isearch-cound-message` or inject the update to isearch-message-suffix sooner the isearch logic that displays information in the minibuffer.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun isearch-count-message ()
  (when isearch-success
   (let* ((string isearch-string))
     (when (>= (length string) 1)
       (let ((before (count-matches string (point-min) (point)))
             (after (count-matches string (point) (point-max))))
         (setq isearch-message-suffix-add
               (propertize (format " (%d of %d)"
                                   before
                                   (+ before
                                      after))
                           'face 'shadow)))))))

(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'isearch-count-message)
```

The initial message is provided by isearch-string, which before typing is that one you used last time. This is why before re-typing you see a wrong number. This can be corrected quite easy.

The initial bad message can be corrected by resetting the value of `isearch-message-suffix-add` in the hook named `isearch-exit-mode`.

UPDATE:

This code is the best one can write. I looked at it today. The edit string is not the same as `isearch-string`, but it's delayed by 1 character. In order to have a correct display, one needs to type C-s or C-r 2 times, for the edit-string to be the same as isearch-string. Isearch does not export in the external environment a variable to have the value of edit-string.

```
(defun isearch-display-count-matches ()
  (if isearch-just-started
      (setq isearch-message-suffix-add "")
      (let ((before (count-matches isearch-string (point-min) (point)))
            (after (count-matches isearch-string (point) (point-max))))
        (setq isearch-message-suffix-add
              (propertize (format " -%s- (%d of %d)" isearch-string
                                  before (+ before after))
                          'face 'isearch-face)))))

(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'isearch-display-count-matches 'end t)
```

And in `isearch-mode-end-hook` I inserted so:

```
(setq isearch-message-suffix-add "")
(remove-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'isearch-display-count-matches t)
```

This works nice for me -- and it displays the isearch-string, to know what to expect at, at each moment.

Comment: I can't find `isearch-exit-mode-conf.el` on my system with or without the `.el` extension. Did you misspell the symbol or did you mean a package file?

Comment: Sorry, without `.el` and without `-conf` :). this is to me :)

Comment: `isearch-mode-end-hook` perhaps?? `C-u M-x apropos-variable` `^isearch.*hook$` `RET` (Emacs 24.3.1)

Comment: Yes. probably yes. I did not check carefully the source code, because the idea is clear. you set to the variable isearch-message-suffix-add to nil or to empty string "" in that hook.